# org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml, jdom

Buenos días soy algo nuevo en estos temas y revisando otras preguntas este es mi problema:

No logro analizar un archivo XML en una instancia de documento JDOM usando SAXBuilder.

Me sale este error:

org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

El codigo que genera este fallo es el siguiente:

```java
 public ArrayList<OpcionesHotel> parseXMLSearchHotels(String response) {
        ArrayList<OpcionesHotel> respuestaSearch = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
            org.jdom2.Document jdomDoc = builder.build(new StringReader(response));
            Element raiz = jdomDoc.getRootElement();
```

El XML que es la variable Response es el siguiente:

```xml
{
    "ServiceId": "2",
    "Error": null,
    "Options": [
        {
            "Id": "eyJPcHRpb25JZCI6eyJTZXJ2aWNlSWQiOm51bGwsIkNvcnJlbGF0aW9uSWQiOiJOIiwiVHJhbnNhY3Rpb25JZGVudGlmaWVyIjoiTiIsIlByb3ZpZGVyTmFtZSI6IlBPQkxBRE8gQUxFSkFORFJJQSIsIlByb3ZpZGVyQ29kZSI6IjU0IiwiT3JpZ2luIjoiTURFIiwiRGVzdGluYXRpb24iOm51bGwsIkRlcGFydHVyZURhdGUiOiIyMDE5LTEyLTAyIiwiUmV0dXJuRGF0ZSI6IjIwMTktMTItMDciLCJBZGFwdGVyR2RzIjoiTiIsIkFkYXB0ZXJOYW1lIjpudWxsLCJGYXJlcyI6eyJUb3RhbEFtb3VudCI6IjE5OTkyMCIsIkN1cnJlbmN5IjpudWxsLCJCYXNlQW1vdW50IjoiMTk5OTIwIiwiVGF4ZXNBbW91bnQiOm51bGx9LCJSb29tcyI6bnVsbH19",
            "NameHotel": "POBLADO ALEJANDRIA",
            "Description": "POBLADO ALEJANDRIA 3",
            "ServiceConditions": "Desayuno - WIFI Se confirma tarifa ecopetrol",
            "NumberStars": "3 Estrellas",
            "Image": "https://t-ec.bstatic.com/images/hotel/max1024x768/311/31170677.jpg",
            "Fares": {
                "TotalAmount": "199920",
                "Currency": "COP",
                "BaseAmount": "199920",
                "TaxesAmount": "0",
                "AdministrativeAmount": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SAX` es para analizar `XML`, tu le estas pasando un `JSON`, nunca va a funcionar así.

**ACTUALIZACION:**

Tienes que hacer estas clases:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Example {

private String serviceId;
private Object error;
private List<Option> options = null;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public String getServiceId() {
return serviceId;
}

public void setServiceId(String serviceId) {
this.serviceId = serviceId;
}

public Object getError() {
return error;
}

public void setError(Object error) {
this.error = error;
}

public List<Option> getOptions() {
return options;
}

public void setOptions(List<Option> options) {
this.options = options;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Fares.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Fares {

private String totalAmount;
private String currency;
private String baseAmount;
private String taxesAmount;
private String administrativeAmount;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public String getTotalAmount() {
return totalAmount;
}

public void setTotalAmount(String totalAmount) {
this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
}

public String getCurrency() {
return currency;
}

public void setCurrency(String currency) {
this.currency = currency;
}

public String getBaseAmount() {
return baseAmount;
}

public void setBaseAmount(String baseAmount) {
this.baseAmount = baseAmount;
}

public String getTaxesAmount() {
return taxesAmount;
}

public void setTaxesAmount(String taxesAmount) {
this.taxesAmount = taxesAmount;
}

public String getAdministrativeAmount() {
return administrativeAmount;
}

public void setAdministrativeAmount(String administrativeAmount) {
this.administrativeAmount = administrativeAmount;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Option.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Option {

private String id;
private String nameHotel;
private String description;
private String serviceConditions;
private String numberStars;
private String image;
private Fares fares;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getNameHotel() {
return nameHotel;
}

public void setNameHotel(String nameHotel) {
this.nameHotel = nameHotel;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public String getServiceConditions() {
return serviceConditions;
}

public void setServiceConditions(String serviceConditions) {
this.serviceConditions = serviceConditions;
}

public String getNumberStars() {
return numberStars;
}

public void setNumberStars(String numberStars) {
this.numberStars = numberStars;
}

public String getImage() {
return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
this.image = image;
}

public Fares getFares() {
return fares;
}

public void setFares(Fares fares) {
this.fares = fares;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Al final usas la biblioteca Gson para el parseo:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Example ejemplo = gson.fromJson(response,Example.class);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias no tenia idea de eso, sabes de alguna forma que pueda analizar el JSON